# regex to add space b/w alphabet and number

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that has characters and numbers
string is like

```
iPhone8s
```

i want the output to be `iPhone 8s`
I have written this code

```
s = 'iPhone8s'
re.sub('(\d+(\.\d+)?)', r' \1 ', s).strip()
```

but it outputs `iPhone 8 s` how can i make the output to be `iPhone 8s`

i only want it for string that contains iPhone in it, i dont want to transform `random8` as `random 8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i only want it for string that contains iPhone

then you have to put the `iPhone` into the regex

```
import re

s = 'iphone8s'
s = re.sub('iPhone(\d+)', r'iPhone \1', s, 0, re.IGNORECASE)
print(s) # iPhone 8s

s = 'random8s'
s = re.sub('iPhone(\d+)', r'iPhone \1', s, 0, re.IGNORECASE)
print(s) # random8s
```

Answer (score 0):

easy to understand and sort if you find for specifically for iphone word  :

```
result='iphone8s'.lower().replace('iphone','iPhone ')
#iPhone 8s
```

Comment: edited the question, please have a look again